# Rank unique by status, group, sub group and start date

Tags: excel, countif

have this formula:

```
=COUNTIF([IDS],$T5&"?*"&"<"&$T5)+COUNTIFS([IDS],$T5,[IDT],"<"&$U5)+COUNTIFS([IDT],$U5,[Start],">"&$E5)+1
```

Trying to assign unique numerical ID but struggle with the conditions.
If TblOccupancy[in] is "yes" then sort by:
1. [IDS] ascending
2. [IDT] ascending
3. [name] descending
4. [start] descending

This is one of the formulas i always struggle with.
If anyone has a minute I would really appreciate some of your brain power.
In the meantime I am going back to basics to try and avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: This question needs sample data (**not** in an image) together with expected results.

Comment: I dont know how to add an attachment on here.
`TblOccupancy `=$B$4:$W$1292
`Names in [start] column`
`Start Dates in [start] column`
`Status "yes", "-" in [in] column`
`Group in [IDS] column`
`SubGroup in [IDT] column`